# are debug symbols loaded into memory on linux?

Tags: linux

Does stripping debug symbols from an executable (or shared library) reduce the amount of memory used?   (I know it reduces the size of the disk file -- what I'm interested in here is that actual RAM used).

Drepper’s paper http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf on p.13 says

> The normal symbol table is not used at run-time and it is therefore
> not necessary to strip a binary of it

OTOH, the man page for strip says

> a stripped binary (which) will occupy less space in RAM

Based on some quick tests, it looks like Drepper is correct (no surprise there), and therefore man page for strip is wrong.

Can anyone help confirm/deny?

Comment: I'd be inclined to look in /proc/[pidno]/maps in both cases

Comment: @Chris Stratton: Pages from mappings are demand-loaded, so `maps` only tells you about address space usage, not actual core usage.

Comment: Well, first, if it's not mapped then it's unlikely to end up taking RAM.  Second, I would think that which portions of the file could be loaded is a question that has a lot more deterministic an answer than which pages one can expect to find loaded into actual physical ram at any given instant, as that depends on details of the system executing it.

Comment: But if you want to take a stab at anecdotally determining what actually is resident at any given instant, /proc/pid/smaps should do

Answer (score 0):

On systems that use readahead to speed up boot and program launch, debug symbols do waste memory in the file cache.

Comment: It would seem possible for the ELF loader to use `madvise(MADV_DONTNEED)` on the ranges corresponding to debug symbols.

Comment: @caf: readahead would have still wasted time reading the data in the first place though.