# What's the difference between prof and gprof?

Tags: c, profiling

Like the title says, I'd like to know which is the difference between the two commands and the results they produce.

From reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8422678/what-does-the-p-and-g-flag-in-compiler/8424688#8424688) I understand gprof requires an extra flag (-g, the same needed for gdb?), but that doesn't give me an answer about the difference between the profilers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`gprof` was invented specifically because `prof` only gives you "self time".
"self time" tells you what fraction of the total time the program counter is found in each routine.
That's fine if the only kinds of "bottlenecks" you need to consider are solved by shaving cycles at the bottom of the call stack.

What about the kind of "bottleneck" that you solve by reducing the number of calls to subroutines?
That's what `gprof` was supposed to help you find, by "charging back" self time to callers.
"inclusive time" in a routine consists of its "self time", plus what bubbles up from the routines it calls.
Here's a simple example of what `gprof` does:

[image]

A calls B ten times, and B calls C ten times, and C does some CPU-intensive loop for 10 sample times.
Notice that none of the samples land in A or B because the program counter spends practically all of its time in C.
`gprof`, by counting the calls, and keeping track of who made them, does some math and propagates time upward.

So you see, a way to speed up this program is to have A call B fewer times, or have B call C fewer times, or both.
`prof` could not give you that kind of information - you'd have to guess.

If you're thinking of using `gprof`, [*be aware of its problems*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1779343/23771), like not giving line-level information, being blind to I/O, getting confused by recursion, and misleading you into thinking certain things help you find problems, like sample rate, call graph, invocation counts, etc.
Keep in mind that its authors only claimed it was a measurement tool, not a problem-finding tool, even though most people think it's the latter.

Answer (score 2):

What I understand is that both of the commands output a similar flat file who looks like :

**Flat profile:**

```
  Each sample counts as 0.01 seconds.
    %   cumulative   self              self     total
   time   seconds   seconds    calls  us/call  us/call  name
   37.50      0.15     0.15    48000     3.12     3.12  Life::neighbor_count(int, int)
   17.50      0.22     0.07                             _IO_do_write
   10.00      0.26     0.04                             __overflow
    7.50      0.29     0.03                             _IO_file_overflow
    7.50      0.32     0.03                             _IO_putc
    5.00      0.34     0.02       12  1666.67 14166.67  Life::update(void)
    5.00      0.36     0.02                             stdiobuf::overflow(int)
    5.00      0.38     0.02                             stdiobuf::sys_write(char const *, int)
    2.50      0.39     0.01                             ostream::operator<<(char)
    2.50      0.40     0.01                             internal_mcount
    0.00      0.40     0.00       12     0.00     0.00  Life::print(void)
    0.00      0.40     0.00       12     0.00     0.00  to_continue(void)
    0.00      0.40     0.00        1     0.00     0.00  Life::initialize(void)
    0.00      0.40     0.00        1     0.00     0.00  instructions(void)
    0.00      0.40     0.00        1     0.00 170000.00  main
```

> The flat profile shows the total amount of time your program spent executing each function.

**gprof** seems to output one more file representing the *call-graph*, it looks like :

**Call graph** :

```
granularity: each sample hit covers 4 byte(s) for 2.50% of 0.40 seconds

    index % time    self  children    called     name
                    0.02    0.15      12/12          main [2]
    [1]     42.5    0.02    0.15      12         Life::update(void) [1]
                    0.15    0.00   48000/48000       Life::neighbor_count(int, int) [4]
    -----------------------------------------------
                    0.00    0.17       1/1           _start [3]
    [2]     42.5    0.00    0.17       1         main [2]
                    0.02    0.15      12/12          Life::update(void) [1]
                    0.00    0.00      12/12          Life::print(void) [13]
                    0.00    0.00      12/12          to_continue(void) [14]
                    0.00    0.00       1/1           instructions(void) [16]
                    0.00    0.00       1/1           Life::initialize(void) [15]
    -----------------------------------------------

    [3]     42.5    0.00    0.17                 _start [3]
                    0.00    0.17       1/1           main [2]
    -----------------------------------------------
                    0.15    0.00   48000/48000       Life::update(void) [1]
    [4]     37.5    0.15    0.00   48000         Life::neighbor_count(int, int) [4]
    -----------------------------------------------
```

> The call graph shows how much time was spent in each function and its children. From this information, you can find functions that, while they themselves may not have used much time, called other functions that did use unusual amounts of time.

**Finally :**
It seems that *prof* only shows you the time spent in a function while *gprof* shows the call graph to show what is taking time also inside the functions. With that you can find the routines who are taking times inside the functions.