# Changes -g flag in GNU compiler makes in executable for c++

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, gnu

What changes does the -g flag actually make to the executable when added?

Comment: I think this question has been answered here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8422678/what-does-the-p-and-g-flag-in-compiler)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main change will be an increase in the size of the binary, as it will now hold extra debug information. Depending on the target you are building for, it might (or not) have any other effect during execution. For example when generating ELF, all debug information is maintained in a separate section that need not even be loaded into memory unless when running inside a debugger (so it will not require more actual memory to run even thought the binary is larger)

Comment: May I ask what ELF stands for?

Comment: @StephenJacob: [Executable and Linkable Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format). It is the binary format in some platforms including linux.

Comment: Rodriguez: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Basically it includes more information about the source of your program that would otherwise be lost in the compilation process. This includes more symbol names, and the line numbers that pieces of machine code correspond to. See [this reference](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gdb/gdb_17.html) for a bit more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Debugging informations are added to your executable. See this [link](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html).